# Move the li position in a drop down by string name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am trying to move the position of a specific li string name to the top of the drop down.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="guestdetails_country-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-    widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom w230 ui-selectmenu-open" aria-labelledby="guestdetails_country-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" style="z-index: 9999; width: 230px; height: 250px; top: 393px; left: 620px;" aria-disabled="false" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item- 8">
    <li class="" role="presentation">
        <a id="" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#"></a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1"  href="#">Afghanistan</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">Åland Islands</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
        <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">Albania</a>
    </li>
```

**jquery**
tried it like this but did not work

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $('#guestdetails_country-menu li a')
    $select.find('Albania').insertBefore($select.find('li:eq(1)'));
});
```

Also tried selecting the text this way but did not work either

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $('#guestdetails_country-menu li a').text()
    $(this).html($(this).html('Albania').insertBefore($select.find('li:eq(1)')));
});
```

by selecting the eq works, but I want a more efficient code

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $('#guestdetails_country-menu')
    $select.find('li').eq(237).insertBefore($select.find('li:eq(1)'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example using JQuery **[contain](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** selector like following :

```js
$(function(){
  var select_element = $('#guestdetails_country-menu');
  select_element.find("li a:contains('Albania')").parent().insertBefore(select_element.find('li:eq(1)'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="guestdetails_country-menu" class="ui-selectmenu-menu ui-widget ui-    widget-content ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown ui-corner-bottom w230 ui-selectmenu-open" aria-labelledby="guestdetails_country-button" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" style="z-index: 9999; width: 230px; height: 250px; top: 393px; left: 620px;" aria-disabled="false" aria-activedescendant="ui-selectmenu-item- 8">
  <li class="" role="presentation">
    <a id="" aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">First element</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1"  href="#">Afghanistan</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">Åland Islands</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a aria-selected="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" href="#">Albania</a>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you don't actually want that empty `LI` at the top, I would remove that, and just run:

```
var $select = $("#guestdetails_country-menu");
$select.prepend($select.find("li:has(a:contains('Albania'))"))
```

(prepend will work the same as insertBefore(el0), just a bit more concise)

Comment: Hi, the empty li at the top it's selected by default when no country is selected, or the user can select the empty space if they don't want to select any country. but yes I ended up using `li:has(a:contains('Albania`, but I need to use either prependTo or insertbefore in order to keep the blank space on top and it worked :)